# AutoMapper Custom Value Resolvers async

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I want to convert `BotViewModel` to `Bot` using AutoMapper.

There is an example input below from type `BotViewModel`. If I want to add a new bot to the database, that model should be matched/mapped to `Bot` model and Bot's foreign keys should be resolved.

In other words, `BotViewModel.Symbol` should be matched to `CryptoPair.Symbol` and `BotViewModel.Interval` to `TimeInterval.Interval`.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Bot 1",
  "status": true,
  "symbol": "LTCBTC",
  "interval": 6
}
```

My code below is working exactly as I described it above. It uses http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html. The thing is that I want to make `_context.CryptoPairs.FirstOrDefault` async `FirstOrDefault => FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

I want to do that because I feel like that's not the best practice. Basically, I'm looking for an advice if that's okay or not. By the way, if the symbol or interval cannot be matched because it simply doesn't exist in the database, `var bot = _mapper.Map<Bot>(botViewModel);` should just throw an exception which is later handled by my controller.

```
public class CryptoPairResolver : IValueResolver<BotViewModel, Bot, int>
{
    private readonly BinanceContext _context;

    public CryptoPairResolver(BinanceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Resolve(BotViewModel source, Bot destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _context.CryptoPairs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Symbol == source.Symbol).Id;
    }
}

public class TimeIntervalResolver : IValueResolver<BotViewModel, Bot, int>
{
    private readonly BinanceContext _context;

    public TimeIntervalResolver(BinanceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Resolve(BotViewModel source, Bot destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _context.TimeIntervals.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Interval == source.Interval).Id;
    }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BotViewModel, Bot>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CryptoPairId, opt => opt.MapFrom<CryptoPairResolver>())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TimeIntervalId, opt => opt.MapFrom<TimeIntervalResolver>());
    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class Bot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int CryptoPairId { get; set; }
    public CryptoPair CryptoPair { get; set; }

    public int TimeIntervalId { get; set; }
    public TimeInterval TimeInterval { get; set; }
}

public class BotViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public KlineInterval Interval { get; set; }
}

public class CryptoPair
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public List<Bot> Bots { get; set; }
}

public class TimeInterval
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public KlineInterval Interval { get; set; }

    public List<Bot> Bots { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public async Task<Bot> CreateAsync(BotViewModel botViewModel)
{
    // Map BotViewModel to Bot
    var cryptoPair = await _context.CryptoPairs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Symbol == botViewModel.Symbol);

    if (cryptoPair == null)
    {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }

    var timeInterval = await _context.TimeIntervals.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Interval == botViewModel.Interval);

    if (timeInterval == null)
    {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }

    var bot = new Bot
    {
        Name = botViewModel.Name,
        Status = botViewModel.Status,
        CryptoPairId = cryptoPair.Id,
        TimeIntervalId = timeInterval.Id
    };

    // Create code
    _context.Bots.Add(bot);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return bot;
}
```

Comment: For the 1 millionth time: AutoMapper isn't meant for ViewModel -> Persistence/Domain Model conversions. It's for the other way (Domain/Persistance -> Dto/ViewModel). https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/

Comment: @Tseng what do you recommend? To move the functionality in my scoped service and create a new Bot object and match its fields manually instead?

Comment: Weill first you start by removing automapper from this scenarios (ViewModel -> Doman/Persistance Model). Then you construct it as required in code, get the two models from the database based on your folders, then get your model (in case it already exists) and assign the two entities and populate the values, persist. Same way you would do if AutoMapper didn't exist. Use AutoMapper only for the Entity -> ViewModel scenarios

Comment: @Tseng If I understand right, you meant that AutoMapper is made to match models like the Dto model shouldn't contain certain fields like passwords. An example for that is a `User` model and a `UserDto` model that the API shouldn't show passwords because of security reasons. In my case, I can make a Dto for CryptoPair and TimeInterval models to not return `public List<Bot> Bots { get; set; }` which is from the relationships. Did I understand right? Check my edit btw. What I did in the scoped service is called ViewModel and what I explained above is called Dto, right?

Comment: AutoMapper was primary meant for (as the name implies) automatic mapping and flattening (`order.Billing.Street`->`orderViewModel.BillingStreet`) of domain models and view models, commands, or dtos). Never intended for the use in the opposite direction. Just read the linked blog post, its from the AutoMapper author, Jimmy Bogard. _I think using AutoMapper because you don’t want to use the “=” operator is a bit lazy.  Instead, we use it to flatten and reshape, optimizing for the destination type’s environment._

Comment: Also AutoMapping viewModel -> entity with an ORM Framework, is an awful way to get yourself a lot of pain in the ass, cause ORMs track identities by reference, tools like automapper create new instances, messing ORM up really hard and the way they track changes. Have a read: https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/

Comment: @Tseng I read it and got it. So it's basically what I wrote above. If I had a `User` model and a page where I want to display all users, the API shouldn't return the Password field because security reasons, so in result I should create a UserDto model which should contain all fields but not the Password and use AutoMapper. What I don't understand is Dto vs ViewModel naming. Dto is basically the scenario I was talking above about UserDto (Hides particular properties that clients are not supposed to view) and ViewModel is what I had to do in my question (to minimize data)?

Comment: In Context of ASP.NET Core MVC (not necessary true for WebAPI) Dto and ViewModels are mostly the same thing, just named differently. ViewModel comes from MVVM pattern, where ViewModel also had presentation logic, change notification and prepares the data for the view to consume. In ASP.NET Core, the presentation logic is skipped (since there is no data-binding like in WPF/UWP Apps and no message notifications when a vlaue changes). So in ASP.NET ViewModel is mostly just an Dto. Dto are commonly used when you communicate between domain boundaries (if DDD is applied). But its a bit out of scope

Comment: @Tseng, thanks! I had more time and I read those articles again and again, including additional sources. As much as I understood, Mr. Jimmy says that it's not meant for two-way binding which by itself means that it is used to convert: Bot -> BotDto (`CreateMap<Bot, BotDto>();`) and not BotDto -> Bot (`CreateMap<Bot, BotDto>();`) because it doesn't really have required information about EF and not thread safe. It might reduce the performance and the rest negative factors mentioned in the 2nd article you gave me. Is that all you wanted to say?

Comment: @Tseng If so, why did he invent `ReverseMap()` or simply BotDto -> Bot is not intended while EF operations like this one `context.DetailSet.Add(...)` are presented? Please check my scoped service: https://pastebin.com/W8vdDPxK and tell me if that's okay.

Comment: @Tseng, please check all of my three comments. This is another of my services where EF isn't involved in any of the properties for the conversion from CryptoPairDto to CryptoPair. https://pastebin.com/7hjAnUsA. Check both pastebins, if they both are fine, it would mean that I complete got your point.

Comment: @nop Your pastebins seem to be expired.